# Is there a way to kill Shinigamis with a death note?

Tags: death-note

I know that if you write the name of a shinigami in a notebook he won't die. But let's say I would write something like this:

**7.11.2014.**

John Zeürtö gets scared to death.

At **11:30**, John Zeürtö enters a dark alley (name of the alley) with a knife and threatens everyone who is there. Then he sees something not from this world. He attempts to kill the monster, but is unsuccessful. He then sees that the monster is coming closer to him and then he dies at **11:45**.

With this, the shinigami would technically kill a human without a death note. And since shinigami die when they kill a human without a death note, this could work. But I also have another example.

**8.11.2014.**

Bob Johnson dies of a neck fracture.

At **1:30 pm** Bob Johnson enters a mall (name of the mall). At **1:35** he takes cocaine and destroys certain things in the mall. At **1:40** he notices a little piece from a death note in the last regal from a TV store. Then he sees something not from this world and shoots at the monster. After he realizes that the monster is still alive he runs to a staircase to flee. But the monster follows him and pushes him. He falls down the staircase and then he breaks his neck.

Would that work?

Comment: The second one literally has the Shinigami pushing the victim.  I don't think you can control someone who is not being killed by the death note.  In the first the shinigami does nothing to hurt the victim; If you saw my face over skype and died of horror, I don't think I would be charged with murder. That being said, he might just die of a heart attack as he cannot see the monster unless he touched the book.

Comment: where exactly did you read that a Shinigami dies if they kill *without* a death note? from my recollection a Shinigami dies one of 2 ways, prevents the assigned death of a human or failure to keep adding years to their own lived

Comment: with the second example, you put in that Bob *"notices a little piece from a death note"*, unless Bob has prior knowledge of the Death note this will cause the entire thing to fail as Light demonstrated when he tried to have a prisoner write *"i know L suspects the Japanese Police"*, that failed. when Light killed Kiichiro Osoreda he never states in the Death Note the paper Osoreda picked up a piece of the Death Note, juts that after picking up a piece of paper he then sees an otherworldly phantom and empties his gun before fleeing and getting hit by a car

Comment: -1 I downvoted, because I feel like these things were well explained throughout the series. Especially the fact on how to kill a Death God. I'm curious though to the reason why you would think that a Death God would die if he would kill a human without the use of the death note.

Comment: There are laws in the world of gods of death. If a god of death should break the law, there are 9 leve ls of severity starting at Level 8 and going up to Level 1 plus the Extreme Level. For severity levels above 3 the god of death will be killed after being punished.
For example, killing a human without using the Death Note is considered as the Extreme Level. See? A shinigami will die when he kills a human without a death note. @Peter Raeves

Comment: It's a actual rule from death note. @Memor-X

Comment: @PeterRaeves just for reference DarkYagami is talking about How to Use: XLVI. And also with those laws aren't they laws of the Shingami Realm, do they apply to Shinigami who are tied to the human world when a death note they own is possessed by a human cause I assumed that if a Shinigami is unaffected by the time limit rule (can't remember the number, it's the one that talks about how long they can be in the human world) then they aren't considered to be in e Shinigami Realm

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way you can kill a Death God with the Death Note.**

In the first example, the human got scared of the Death God and died. The Death God did not do anything. He just stood there and then the human died, so why would he be held responsible for just being and not doing anything?

In the second example, you write that the Death God pushes him down the stairs. This situation is impossible, therefore only the cause of death will take effect (see rule LV below). The situation is impossible, because the Death God will never kill a human being without the Death Note, because it would result in their death.

> [LV](http://deathnote.wikia.com/wiki/Rules_of_the_Death_Note#How_to_Use:_LV): In the occasion where the cause of death is possible but the situation is not, only the cause of death will take effect for that victim. If both the cause and the situation are impossible, that victim will die of heart attack. )

Comment: I think you can manipulate a person who's names i not written down in the death note. For example when i wrote: John Smith gets stabbed to death, then the death note will most likely manipulate a person with a knife who will then kill him. Also you can just write: sees a piece paper on a ground and picks it up, and make sure that this piece is from a death note. Also when you write: John Smith car accident, that means that the death note will control someone without killing him to actually run over the victim.

Comment: @DarkYagami i wouldnt call that manipulating. The person driving the car was already driving that car even without the death note. You cant for example say "john sees a man do twenty backflips before he stabs him" cos the backflips wouldnt have occured naturally. I will look up XVLI before i change my reply then if such rule would really exist. I dont remember it being mentioned in the manga though

Comment: @DarkYagami the rule seems to exist but it still wouldnt be possible to kill a god that way. I cant find a rule that says other people cant be manipulated into doing improbable things, but X does say that other lifes may not be influenced and may not directly cause the death of others. XXVI confirms this

Comment: If he touches a piece from the death note then he will see the shinigami. Also the death note says that by killing a human the lifespan of others may be shortened. @Peter Raeves

Comment: @DarkYagami indirectly it is allowed. But ur goal is to kill the death god so that is quite directly influencing him. Its like saying "john commits suicide after poisining his family". It is not sure whether they die from the poison but I dont think this would be similarily possible. Although not sure cos technically that criminal did hijack a buss thus dirctly influencing and endangering other peoples lifes... it might come down to VI.2 were we dont know

Comment: I think it would be possible. But let's say that i would write for example: John Smith gets stabbed to death at 12.11.2014 11:30. Someone would stab him. And then, the police finds him. Then, he get's the death penalty and voilà his lifespan would be shortened. So you can say, that this would work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. as stated in the series, they die from using a death note to prolong a humans life out of love, and they just crumble to dust. Where did you even get the new rule that they can't kill a human without a death note or they die too? that's not in the series.

Answer (score -1):

A god of death can only die if he falls in love with a human or he intercepts with a humans life span. Or anyone can die if they interfere with another persons life span.

Answer (score -2):

A shinigami(god of death) can die if he/she falls in love with human and kill somewone who was to be responsible for humans death. Any shinigami can die if he interfeares with other shinigamis lifespan.

Comment: Do you have any sources to go along with that?

Comment: Deth node dude :p